# apache allowencodedslashes NoDecode option not valid in apache 2.2.3?

Tags: apache

apache docs say that as of 2.2, the NoDecode option has been added to the AllowEncodedSlashes directive. On the server, apache reports:

/usr/sbin/httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.3
Server built:   Feb  8 2012 08:19:50

and yet, when I include the directive in my virtualhost, the file no longer passes syntax checking, with an error about only On and Off being supported. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it appears the docs say 2.2.18, which is higher than "3" in this case.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes